# What can cause a UV to not copy properly?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to copy a UV map from 1 object to another identical object but the UV coordinates don't match up.  Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?[image: Correct UV Mapping]

[image: Incorrect UV Mapping]

[image: The UV Map]

First Image is the Good UV map I'm trying to copy from.  Second image is of course the result of copying the UVs from the first image.  The third image is the UV map from BOTH objects, they are identical which is why I'm confused.  When I select a section of vertices, say the leg for instance, the vertices on the UV are mostly hair UV instead of the leg UVs (Fourth Image)[image: Broken UV Map].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your two objects are not identical.

When you copy UV, it's copying via topology.  Basically what that means, in this case, is that it copies the data in the order that the face-corners are stored.  If one model has its face-corners stored in a different order than the other, different face-corners will get the UV than expected, and the UV map will look the same, but the textures will be in completely different spots.

Somewhere, some process made it so that these seemingly identical models are not identical, not under the hood.  Many import and export algorithms don't pay much attention to index order, and can leave you with models that are subtly different like this.

If you need to restore index order for something, you can look into a "mesh sort" operation to try to get their mesh data sorted identically, but it's probably not worth it-- instead, these are otherwise identical models, so just use the one with the UV you want.

Comment: I see, was gonna rig the second model since it's positioning is easier, but of course I set up the UVs on the first model lol.  Oh well, thanks for the help.